# Clearing styles once attempt is made

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my spelling game the user clicks on the letters to make them animate in to the slots on the grid to spell the words.

I have designed it so when a word is spelt correctly, a style is applied called "wordglow2" that makes the word disappear and reveal the picture behind - which is the aim of the game.

When the user gets the word wrong the he/she is given a second attempt at the word. When the user gets the word wrong a style called "wordglow4" is applied to the word which makes it glow red. The problem is the style applied to wrong words does not go away to clear the space for another attempt.

**How do I make the styles dissapear 2 seconds after the 3rd letter of the word is clicked (attempt is made)?**

This code applies the styles depending on whether the word is right or wrong...

```
   if (!$('.drop-box.spellword:not(.occupied)').length) {
       var wordIsCorrect = 0;
       $('.drop-box.spellword').each(function() {
          if ($(this).attr("data-letter") == $(this).find("div").attr("data-letter")) {
                wordIsCorrect++;
            }
        });
        console.log(wordIsCorrect);
        console.log($('.drop-box.spellword').length);
        if ($('.drop-box.spellword').length == wordIsCorrect) {

                $('.drop-box.spellword').addClass('wordglow2');
                $(right).val('Well Done!');
                $(right).show();
                audioS.play();
                $('.counter').html(completeWords + '/6').show();
                $(wrong).hide();
                $('.minibutton').prop('disabled', false);

            } else {

                $('.drop-box.spellword').addClass("wordglow4").css('color', 'transparent');
                $(wrong).val('Try Again');
                $('.minibutton').prop('disabled');
                $(wrong).show();
                audioF.play();
                $('.counter').html(completeWords + '/6').show();
                $(right).hide();
                $('.minibutton').prop('disabled', true);

            }


        }
    });

}

var completeLetters = $('.wordglow2').length;
var completeWords = (completeLetters / 3);
$('.counter').html(completeWords + '/6');

if (completeWords == 3) {
    $('table').fadeOut(2000);
}

var incompleteWords = $('.spellword').hasClass('.wordglow4').length;
if (incompleteWords == 3) {
    $('.minibutton').prop('disabled', false);
}
});
```

I have tried this...

```
if $('.drop-box.spellword').hasClass("wordglow4") {
               $("wordglow4").fadeOut(2000);                   
            }
```

Here is a working fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/smilburn/3qaGK/25/

Comment: Can you post a jsFiddle with a working example of your game?

Comment: For me the letters don't get cleared from the box either, not just that the class doesn't reset. So are you sure the problem you think you're having (the class not being removed) is the real problem?

Also, from a usability point of view you seem to have two buttons, only one of which will work at any given time, and none while you're playing a word. Am I right? In that case, a modal dialog with the appropriate button in between the words might be more appropriate, especially since it is what looks like a game for children.

Comment: The next button will not let you progress until you have completed the word and the replay button is to give them the sound again in order to help them. I know the next button is not currently working, but that is what is supposed to do. Could you maybe help me with that? @Jan

Comment: Like I said, from a usability point of view having a button that does not work is not very intuitive. I'd remove the button and make it a modal popup upon correct completion of the word. You also have a "play" icon next to a "skip" icon that have completely different functions. I'd also change the "play" icon to a question mark and the word "Replay" to "Hint" or "Play clue" or something like that.

Comment: Actually I'm hard pressed to help you with the programming because I don't quite understand how it's supposed to work. What's supposed to happen when you've entered the wrong word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand quite what you want to do, but something like this might cut it:

```
                $('.drop-box.spellword')
                    .animate({ 'opacity': 1 }, 2000, function()
                             {
                                $(this)
                                    .removeClass('wordglow4')
                                    .removeClass('occupied')
                                    .html('')
                                    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cTGGA/

Comment: thanks. I will have to look into making the button a modal pop up @Jan

Answer (score 1):

User the [removeClass](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/removeClass#overview) method to do that. You can put a duration/animation on the removeClass call itself:

```
$('.drop-box.spellword').removeClass("wordglow4", "2000");
```

This removes the class and animates the transition, probably what you are looking for.

Comment: But I need it to stay for 2 seconds after @Jeeoen Moons

Comment: Just added a second way to do it, probably better for your purpose!

Comment: Thanks but now it fades the whole thing away. I just want the style "wordglow4" to dissapear. Have you looked at the fiddle? @Jeroen Moons

Comment: Thanks. Would I just use the if statement I had before? @Jeroen Moons

Comment: No you don't even need to, if the class is there, it will be removed, otherwise nothing happens

Comment: I have added 2 other styles to remove and they won't. Is there any change you could tell me why they don't work http://jsfiddle.net/smilburn/3qaGK/26/ @Jeroen Moons

Comment: Instead of doing this: removeClass('wordglow').removeClass('wordglow4').removeClass('wordglow3') try this: removeClass('wordglow wordglow4 wordglow3')

Comment: What about the (2000)? @Jeroen Moons

Comment: Is the line that with removeClass ever actually executed? Or is something else going wrong so it never gets to that point?

Comment: How do you mean? @Jeroen Moons

Comment: You say the removeClass statement doesn't "work", but does your script ever execute the removeClass statement? Or does your script go wrong somewhere before ever getting to the removeClass statement?

Comment: The wordstyle4 removes but not he others @Jeroen Moons

Comment: Have you checked that using firebug or similar? Maybe the classes are gone but your css somehow makes it look like they are still there

Comment: I had a look in firebug and it isn't getting rid of the class. Could you have a play with the fiddle to get it working? @Jeroen Moons